# Copy and paste as values cell contents upon update

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that creates new rows when work is added.

Column H contains a checkbox that outputs true/false into Column J, which a formula in column I uses with a custom formula to show the username.

The issue is that the username will change to whoever is logged in and not stay as who checked the box in the first place.

My theory is I need a code that checks whenever column J changes to true and then copy and pastes as values the cell in the same row but in column I

I have the below:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Excel.Range)
If target.Column = 10 Then
thisrow = target.Row
If target.value = “TRUE” Then
Range (“I” & thisrow) = Range (“I” & thisrow).Value
End if
End if
End sub
```

This works, but only if I go into the cell in J and hit enter, it doesn’t recognise the change from the checkbox

Comment: You need to use the [Worksheet.Change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change). Do some research on it and give it a try yourself. If you get stuck or errors come back with your code and ask a question related to it (see [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)).

Comment: Ah, well, obviously a value change in a cell using the checkbox is equivalent to a value change because of a forumla. And the `_change` event is olny triggered by a real cell change but not by a change with a formula. Then the only solution I can imagine is linking a macro to the checkbox that does the username entry for you.